# div left responsive image fixed 100% height and div right text scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-position

How to create a left div with responsive fixed image and a right div with scrollable text if text is bigger than screen. When you resize the page, only the right div change and go under the left div when the screen is less than 1024px for example

here is a screenshot who show what i'm looking for: `http://www.500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/fancy/brouillon2.jpg`

Comment: Where's the screenshot?

Comment: I put a link here because i loaded it but we can't watch it ?!?

Comment: @fatyfatoumata You should look into Bootstrap. Does a lot of this for you.

Comment: I would use CSS floats and media queries to solve this.

Comment: At this time i'm only using html and css, did you think I can do this with that @MaximillianLaumeister ?? but if you can send me an example of bootstrap it'll be nice Grmpy

Comment: @faty What exactly are you trying to achieve?? Bootstrap is good but way too bloated if you're only trying to achieve this.

Comment: I put an answer @AndrewLyndem

Comment: Remove that and post it as a comment faty. Replies need to be posted as comments. Only solutions to issues are posted as answers.

Comment: @Andrewlyndem at this time this is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/d2b1jhxb/



and here is what i'm looking for: http://www.500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/fancy/brouillon2.jpg

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Check the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a media query to your css for restting your css properties to  different values on particular widths like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
    #left_side  {   
        width:100%;
    }
    #content{
        width:100%;
        position:static;
        margin: 0px;
    }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with above code: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/d2b1jhxb/1/

(Increase/decrease the output screen size to see it working)

Comment: When you resize the page, only the right div change and go under the left div when the screen is less than 1024px for example

Comment: Yes, that is what I've done on the fiddle above. What exactly do you want then?

Comment: yes but before the right div go under the left one, can we have only the right div who change width before to go under ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean faty.

Comment: you can see it on my screenshot, the 3 images represent in fact different level of resized page, i want the same result. Only the right div who shrink, the left div must stay at 50% width ;)

Comment: Oh so you dont want the right div to go under, but you want the left div with image to shrink on smaller screens??

Comment: In fact, when we have a large screen (1920x1080 for example) i want a left div with image 50% width and right div with text 50% width. When you resized the page before the right div goes under the left one, i want that only the right div shrink when we resized the page ;) and when the right div loose 20% of her width, at this time i want it under the left one !!

Comment: Oh I see. You just need to add more media queries like the one above and increase `width:xx%;` accordingly.

Comment: oh really so to have a left div who stay always with 50% width, we only need media queries ?

Comment: Yes media queries is enough for that. Just add 50% width to both the divs for your standard width dimension and then just change the values as required in other width dimensions.

Comment: yep it works it's perfect, I think i've what i asking for ;D

Comment: Nice!! Glad I could help